# Drawing hexagon image using Swift 4

Tags: swift

```
public func roundedPolygonPath(rect: CGRect, lineWidth: CGFloat, sides: NSInteger, cornerRadius: CGFloat, rotationOffset: CGFloat = 0) -> UIBezierPath {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    let theta: CGFloat = CGFloat(2.0 * M_PI) / CGFloat(sides) // How much to turn at every corner
    let offset: CGFloat = cornerRadius * tan(theta / 2.0)     // Offset from which to start rounding corners
    let width = min(rect.size.width, rect.size.height)        // Width of the square

    let center = CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x + width / 2.0, y: rect.origin.y + width / 2.0)

    // Radius of the circle that encircles the polygon
    // Notice that the radius is adjusted for the corners, that way the largest outer
    // dimension of the resulting shape is always exactly the width - linewidth
    let radius = (width - lineWidth + cornerRadius - (cos(theta) * cornerRadius)) / 2.0

    // Start drawing at a point, which by default is at the right hand edge
    // but can be offset
    var angle = CGFloat(rotationOffset)

    let corner = CGPoint(x: center.x + (radius - cornerRadius) * cos(angle),y: center.y + (radius - cornerRadius) * sin(angle))
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: corner.x + cornerRadius * cos(angle + theta),y: corner.y + cornerRadius * sin(angle + theta)))

    for _ in 0..<sides {
        angle += theta

        let corner = CGPoint(x: center.x + (radius - cornerRadius) * cos(angle),y:  center.y + (radius - cornerRadius) * sin(angle))
        let tip = CGPoint(x: center.x + radius * cos(angle),y: center.y + radius * sin(angle))
        let start = CGPoint(x: corner.x + cornerRadius * cos(angle - theta),y:  corner.y + cornerRadius * sin(angle - theta))
        let end = CGPoint(x: corner.x + cornerRadius * cos(angle + theta), y: corner.y + cornerRadius * sin(angle + theta))

        path.addLine(to: start)
        path.addQuadCurve(to: end, controlPoint: tip)
    }

    path.close()

    // Move the path to the correct origins
    let bounds = path.bounds
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -bounds.origin.x + rect.origin.x + lineWidth / 2.0, y: -bounds.origin.y + rect.origin.y + lineWidth / 2.0)
    path.apply(transform)

    return path
}


public func createImage(layer: CALayer) -> UIImage {
    let size = CGSizeMake(CGRect.maxX(layer.frame), CGRect.maxY(layer.frame))
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, layer.isOpaque, 0.0)
    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    layer.render(in: ctx!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image!
}

let lineWidth = CGFloat(7.0)
let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 150.0, 150.0)
let sides = 6

var path = roundedPolygonPath(rect, lineWidth, sides, 15.0, rotationOffset: CGFloat(-M_PI / 2.0))

let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
borderLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, path.bounds.width + lineWidth, path.bounds.height + lineWidth)
borderLayer.path = path.CGPath
borderLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
borderLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
borderLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

var image = createImage(borderLayer)}[enter image description here][1]
```

---

I cannot convert the Swift 3  with CGRect and CGSizeMake functions to  latest Swift 4.

The following errors is due to the conversion of Swift 3 example. I have found, 
 'CGRectMake' is unavailable in Swift
 Extensions may not contain stored properties
 'CGSizeMake' is unavailable in Swift
*Im trying to draw the path **

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `CGSizeMake` you now can use `CGSize.init`, e.g. `CGSize(width: 100, height: 50)`.

Instead of the static function `CGRect.maxX` you now can use the member method of the same name: `CGRect.maxX(layer.frame)` becomes `layer.frame.maxX`.